# RPC with a remote node

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

I know this question has been asked so many times. But I have not been able to solve my problem.

I am trying to connect to a remote node located on a server.

My server is running geth on rinkeby and RPC should be enabled thanks to this command:

```
admin.startRPC("0.0.0.0", 8545, "*", "web3,db,net,eth")
```

In my code (NodeJS), I have the following:

```
function getNode(callback) {
    var web3;
    console.log(web3);
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://X.X.X.X:8545"));
    console.log(web3);
    if (web3 != null) {
        console.log("GOT WEB3");
        callback(null, web3);
    } else {
        console.log("did not get web3");
        callback("ERROR", web3);
    }
}
```

The web3 variable is undefined at the first log, and is returning an object after I get the HTTP provider.

However, I have this error in my console:

> Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
>       at Object.InvalidResponse (D:\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:38:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (D:\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:119:24)

What I have done wrong?

Edit: TCP and UDP are all openned on port 8545.

**UPDATE 1**

Current command to launch geth:

```
geth --rinkeby console -rpc -rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

Current NodeJS code:

```
function getNode(callback) {
    var web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://server_external_ip:8545/"), function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            callback("ERROR", web3);
        } else {
            console.log(web3.isConnected());
            callback(null, web3);
        }
    });
}
```

This is what netstat gives me:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8545                 :::*                    LISTEN      3565/geth
```

Result: serverless gives me a timeout. If no timeout indicated, it runs infinitely without getting anything.

Comment: which version of `Web3` do you `require` in your code?

Comment: I require 1.0.0 beta.26 @ValidityLabs-Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make geth listen on the IP address from which your server can be reached externally:

```
admin.startRPC(<external ip address>, 8545, "*", "web3,db,net,eth")
```

If you specify the localhost, geth accepts only local connections, i. e. connections that come from the same machine, but not from remote.

Comment: Makes sense. But it returns this `Error: listen tcp MY.IP.IS.HERE:8545: bind: cannot assign requested address`

Comment: Sounds like the port is already used by some server. Have you checked, e.g with `lsof -i TCP| fgrep LISTEN` (on Linux)?

Comment: It only gives the following: `geth    2809 myname   33u  IPv6  47912      0t0  TCP *:30303 (LISTEN)`  Same error for random ports

Comment: Just checked the error message. It's not about the port but the address. Are you sure about the IP address? If you are using a VM in the cloud, the VM usually has an internal and an external IP address

Comment: I tried with the external address and internal one. Only the internal one worked. But when I try to send a request, I still have the same error as described in the question

Comment: Yes, you will get the error with the internal address. You really need to set geth to the external address. Hard to say from here what is the cause, looks rather like an issue with the server configuration. I would check if there is a firewall which blocks listening

Comment: But I don't understand. if I specify "0.0.0.0" it should listen on every interface of my machine. So it should work (even if not secured)

Comment: Well, with current config it just loads indefinitely... (no timeout set on my server who asks for connexion)

Comment: Hi, a bit late. Even your solution works, I want to launch rpc when launching geth, without having to do it manually. But using flags just does not work (check question for flags), whatever the order I put them.

Comment: Sure not, since the options go with two minus signs. Try --rpc and --rpcaddr instead of -rpc and -rpcaddr

Comment: Already tried that, same thing :S

Comment: it says: `Error: HTTP server already running on 0.0.0.0:8545`